# Facebook C# SDK 6.0.10 - How to use GetTaskAsync with FQL request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I use facebook C# SDK 6.0.10 and I try to send a FQL request like this:

```
        var fbClient = new FacebookClient(m_accessToken);

            fbClient.GetCompleted +=
                (o, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error == null)
                    {
                        dynamic result = e.GetResultData();
                           ....
                    }
                };

            var query = string.Format("SELECT domain_id FROM domain_admin WHERE owner_id=1234");
            fbClient.GetTaskAsync(query);
```

I receive an error: **"(OAuthException) (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist "SELECT domain_id FROM domain_admin WHERE owner_id=1234"**

If I try the same syntax in the "Facebook API Explorer" it works and I have a response.

How to use the FQL request with Facebook C# SDK 6.0.10 and GetTaskAsync?

Thanks for yor help.

Answer (score 0):

http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests

```
dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("fql", query");
```

If you are using `GetTaskAsync` it is recommended to use async/await if it is supported. or use `ContinueWith` instead of `GetCompleted`.